# How do I make include find more than one match per line?

Tags: include

Here's an excerpt from a file where `aoe(file)` should be treated like an import:

```
  ["Cyclone" 37 {"Move +0" "Attack +0, aoe(aoes/tri-melee.rkt)" "Consume Air: Instead, Attack +1, aoe(aoes/ring1-melee.rkt)"}]
```

I have an `include` setting to find "aoe" files (and other files) that works:

```
let &l:include = '\v(import-monsters "\zs[^"]*\ze"|aoe\(\zs[^)]*\ze\))'
```

However, it only finds the first file on the line (`:checkpath!` includes `aoes/tri-melee.rkt` but not `aoes/ring1-melee.rkt`). If I split the line between the two `aoe()` bits, both are found.

---

1. Is this the usual function of `include`? It's not documented as only processing the first match in a line, as far as I can tell, though `:help include-search` strongly hints that this is the case.
2. Is there a way to check for includes more than once on a line? I could imagine using a more permissive pattern like `aoes(.*)` and then using `includeexpr` to extract multiple matches, but I don't think `includeexpr` is supposed to return a list (nor can I find documentation for what happens if it does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the usual function of `include`?

Yes, the search for includes a) is done in one pass only, and b) only searches for one filename on each line.

> Is there a way to check for includes more than once on a line?

AFAIK no.

FWIW, it is not even possible to have both a `define` and an `include` match on the same line.

> but I don't think `includeexpr` is supposed to return a list (nor can I find documentation for what happens if it does).

The job of `includeexpr` is to extrapolate a more usable filename from *the* filename found by `include`.

---

Reference: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/search.c#L3325, https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/findfile.c#L1888, and too much time wasted battling this.

Comment: Sad, but thanks. "Too much time": I guess I can search, but it sounds like you might have had some discussions with Bram or vim-dev about tweaking these options to catch all matches on a line?

Comment: Some denial-heavy discussions, but mostly informal and a lot of trial and error. ATM neither `include` nor `define` can be tweaked to match several times or together on the same line. I didn't go as far as sending a patch, though, because I can barely read C. Maybe you will have more luck.

Comment: Got it, thanks.